# laravel data pagination is not working

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, laravel-blade

I am using data tables in laravel but pagination does not work. when i added static data in table it is working. May I know what did I missed out or the reason for it not working? Thanks in advance.

```
@section('content')


<div class='panel panel-default'>
   <div class='panel-body'>
    <table id ="allPostTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>S.No.</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Category</th>
           <th>Author Name</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Share</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       @foreach($posts as $post)
        <tr> 
          <td>{{ $post->id }}</td>
              @if(strlen ($post->post_title)  > 0)
                <td>{{$post->post_title}}<br>{{ $post->p_post_title }} </td>
              @else
                <td><a href="{{ url('posts/' . $post->id . '/edit') }}" class="btn-primary btn-xs">Edit</a></td>
              @endif
            <td>{{ $post->category->category or '' }}</td>
           <td>{{$post->post_author}}</td>
          <td>{{$post->created_at}}</td>
            <td></td>
          <td><a href="{{ url('posts/' . $post->id . '/edit') }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Edit</a>
            <a href="{{ url('posts/' . $post->id) }}" class="btn bg-orange btn-xs">View</a></td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@stop
@section('script')
```

javaScript Code:

```
  @section('script')
    <!-- data tables -->
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $('#allPostTable').DataTable( {
          "paging": true, 
          "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        } );
    </script>
    @stop
```

Comment: I suggest you `yajra/laravel-datatables-html` instead of datatable

Comment: https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables-html

Comment: @Neha have you noticed any error in console?

Comment: @parantap parashar there is no error in console

Comment: @Neha This is strange as everything seems almost fine. Could you please share the HTML created of the table from browser's "Inspect Element"?

Comment: @parantap parashar
please see the link:
https://jsfiddle.net/5bs0brkf/1/

Comment: Can you show me your models?

Comment: working fine now. the problem  was pagination on back-end. Thanks for your time.